# Memcache / Memcached issue on CentOs 6.7 - Cannot find save handler 'memcached'

Tags: centos, memcached

I tried installing memcache and memcached on centos 6.7 running php 5.4

Had few errors etc.

But now the phpinfo() shows:

[image]
[image]

The error log shows this error:

> Cannot find save handler 'memcached'

The php.ini has:

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"
```

The error disappears if I used:

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path =t"tcp://127.0.0.1:11211"
```

But I want to use memcached.

Or is it fine to use any of them?

So 2 questions:

1. How can I make memcached work too?
2. Is it fine to use memcache or memcached both? Or does it make any difference?

Thanks :)